# In Linux can I use libusb to read from a keyboard while the kernel still drives this keyboard?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, keyboard, driver, libusb

I have a USB keyboard attached to a Linux machine and I want to use `libusb` to get informed about keyboard events.

Currently I can only handle the keyboard exclusively - i.e. the keyboard won't act as input device any more (and thus I have to attach another keyboard to the same machine for interaction)

Is there a way to use `libusb` in a way that allows the device I read from to be handled by the kernel simultaneously?

Comment: Could this be better placed on superuser?

Comment: Well, don't think so - I'm writing an application in C/C++ and wonder if there's an approach (most likely related to the libusb API) which allows me to use a library in a way I need

Comment: Ok, just a recommendation but you should probably mention that in the question.

Comment: Why do you want to use libusb for this and not the /dev/input stuff?